# Disable Home button android | Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How can we disable the Home button on phonegap for android. In android there were some solutions but they do not seem to be working on android 4.x

Is there some workaround we can disable the same. I am using cordova 4.0

Comment: You can't disable the home button on Android

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to overwrite or disable home button in android.

Comment: Well, this is not true, there are multiple methods. One of them consits in creating an app launcher / kiosk app.